# How best to pop a list item based on the value of a sub-list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 3.8 or 3.9.

I have a list of lists. In reality it will be 550K items long, and the inner lists bigger and more complex, but as a simplified example:

```
big_list = [["a",9,"abc"],["c", 21, "xzy"],["h", 28, "ght"],["d",200,"mfp"],["g",19,"cyp"]]
```

I want to remove a single inner list from the *big_list* based on the value of an item in an inner list. These values will be unique and exist in *only* one inner list.

Since I will have 20 or more threaded processes working with list items, I can't just work on the last item of the *big_list* and pop it when done.

What is the most efficient / effective approach to do this

```
big_list.pop(n)
```

where n is the index of the sublist containing, say, "ght" as it's third element?

This works, but is it the best approach?

```
big_list = [["a",9,"abc"],["c", 21, "xzy"],["h", 28, "ght"],["d",200,"mfp"],["g",19,"cyp"]]
key = "ght"
print(big_list)

count = 0
for item in big_list:
    if item[2] == "ght":
        big_list.pop(count)
        break
    count += 1

print(big_list)
```

Or, is this fine and I'm overthinking it? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the item you're popping, don't use `list.pop`. Mutating a list you're iterating over is going to be a source of bugs and pain in the future.

It would be simpler and more efficient to just filter the list for the elements you want to keep rather than pop the ones you don't want.

```py
filtered = [item for item in big_list if item[2] != "ght"]
```

Alternatively with `filter`,

```py
filtered = list(filter(lambda item: item[2] != "ght", big_list))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. That's not something I'd thought about!

Answer (score 0):

Not a big deal, but using `enumerate` instead of updating a variable yourself will give you a 20-25% speed-up